# My file path is correct but I get 404 error. ASP.NET Web App(.NET FRAMEWORK 4.6.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, routeconfig

Even though my file paths are correct when switching between the views I've created, I get a 404 error and I can't fix it. I tried all kinds of ways, but I guess I am missing some information somewhere.

```
@using EntityLayer.Concrete
@model List<Category>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>
            ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Adı
        </th>
        <th>
            Açıklama
        </th>
        <th>
            Durum
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.CategoryID</td>
            <td>@item.CategoryName</td>
            <td>@item.CategoryDescription</td>
            <td>@item.CategoryStatus</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<a href="~/Views/Category/GetCategoryList.cshtml" class="btn btn-info">GO CategoryList Again</a>
```

My first view,It tries to call itself, but cannot.

```
using BusinessLayer.Concrete;
using EntityLayer.Concrete;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MimariProje.Controllers
{
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        CategoryManager cm=new CategoryManager();
        // GET: Category
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult GetCategoryList() 
        {
            var categoryvalues = cm.GetAllBL();
            return View(categoryvalues);
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddCategory()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddCategory(Category p)
        {
            cm.CategoryAddBL(p);
            return RedirectToAction("GetCategoryList");
        }
    }
}
```

That's controller about category.

Although the path is correct, it does not go to any cshtml file including itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
    
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Context" connectionString="data source=DESKTOP-SNV24R0\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=DbMVC; integrated security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.1.0" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.9.0" newVersion="5.2.9.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

WebConfig-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MimariProje
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

RouteConfig

And the problem->

HTTP404

[image: HTTP404]

I tried giving path in other ways but no change, examples:

1. I tried calling them directly by name since they are in the same file.
   2.I tried calling from the most basic.
2. I tried calling from intermediate files.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are those who switch from front-end to back-end like me and can be novice while learning, instead of removing the post, I answer it myself; when accessing another view from one view
`href="/Category/AddCategory"`

Specify the href like this, do not write the .cshtml part.